# local variable 'author' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sql, django

my views.py is

```
def editbook(request,book_id):
    log.debug("test....")
    if request.POST:
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
        publisher_name =request.POST['publisher_name']
    books=Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id).update(book_name=book_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)
    first_name = request.POST('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST('last_name')
        email = request.POST('email')
        age = request.POST('age')

    author_info = Author.objects.latest('author_id')
    log.debug("test:%s",author_info.author_id)
    author = Author.objects.filter(author_id=author_info.author_id).update(first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name,email=email,age=age)
        return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        books = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        return render_to_response('editbook.html',{'books':books},{'author':author},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

i am getting an error that

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/Samples/DemoApp/DemoApp/views.py", line 70, in editbook
    return render_to_response('editbook.html',{'books':books},{'author':author},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'author' referenced before assignment.
```

Comment: Bind it (`author`) before it's used. End of story. Clean up  the indenting - I am surprised that doesn't throw an indent error - and it should be clear exactly why it isn't assigned.

Comment: can you fix the formatting, `if/else` block seems to be wayward, also if author is assigned in `if` conditon, accessing it in `else` will not work as only one of them will be executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you assigned author value inside of if clause while calling it in return of else block. The error is simply saying you that else block was executed(e.g. request.POST is None). I thing that all you need is to add a default value or move assigning before if statement. 
For example you can do the following:

```
def editbook(request, book_id):
    log.debug("test....")
    author = Author.objects.filter(author_id=author_info.author_id)
    books=Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id)
    if request.POST:
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
        publisher_name =request.POST['publisher_name']
        books=Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id).update(book_name=book_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)
        first_name = request.POST('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST('last_name')
        email = request.POST('email')
        age = request.POST('age')

        author_info = Author.objects.latest('author_id')
        log.debug("test:%s",author_info.author_id)
        author = Author.objects.filter(author_id=author_info.author_id).update(first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name,email=email,age=age)
        return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        books = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        return render_to_response('editbook.html',{'books':books},{'author':author},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code formatting is a bit off but it appears that `author` is only assigned a value if the `If` statement is true. If it's false you're trying to return the `author` value when it hasn't been set.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `author` only gets defined when the `if` condition is true, but you are using it in the `else` block, which will run when `if` condition fails. Its the same as this:

```
def foo(z=None):
    if z:
        i = 'hello'
    else:
        print i


foo()
```

When you execute the above, since `z` is `None`, the `if` condition fails, and `i` is not assigned a value. Since the `if` condition failed, the `else` clause is run, which tries to print `i` which hasn't been defined.